# Issue in QT 4.8.6 with QPA configured on Mac OsX

Tags: macos, qt, qt4, qt4.8, qt5.1

I have a strange issue with the qt libraries built with QPA configured. Configure that I use is

> ./configure -release -opensource -confirm-license -shared -qpa

Once Qt libraries are done compiling,when u check the dependency on each libraries, its giving dependency on each libraries even though linking while building was successful. For example, libQtGui.dylib library shows a dependency on libQtCore.dylib. Similarly for other Qt libraries. Only library that doesnot give any dependency is QTCore dynamic library. Well this is really strange, considering I have built and installed in the same machine and when I try to build a GUI application it links fine but gives dependency issues when i launch it.
I dont have any other qt libraries installed and googled this issue without any help.

Comment: Not sure if it's a QPA issue directly, but the dynamic libs are likely to have *some* dependencies on each other. You'll need the QtCore for aspects of the widget system, whereas QtCore is *just* the barebones of the Qt system so won't need anything else to operate.